# Pyramid ignore missing template variables

Tags: pyramid, chameleon

I have a simple form using Pyramid and I want to use it as a new or update. I don't particularly want to have to create empty dictionary values for all the fields in my form, I just want it to ignore them without raising an exception.

```
<div metal:fill-slot="content">
<form method="POST" action="/studentupdate">
    <input name="id" value="${studentid}" type="hidden" />
    Name: <input type="text" name="studentname" value="${studentname}"/><br />
    Exam Score: <input type="text" name="studentexam" value="${studentexam}"/><br />
    Quiz Score: <input type="text" name="studentquiz" value="${studentquiz}"/><br />
    Homework Score: <input type="text" name="studenthomework" value="${studenthw}"/><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
</div>
```

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can workaround like this
    `${studentexam or ''}`

```
% for i in missing_list or []
<li>${i}</li>
% endfor
```